# how to get each values from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am displaying 2 values from database inside `<h1>` tag.
there more tags in my page.

```
<?php
foreach($arrays as $row)
{
?>
<h1 id="myId"><?php echo  $row['field_name'];?></h1>
<?php
}
```

I want each values for checking. How will I get using JavaScript?.
only two values will get inside `<h1>` tag.

please help.

Comment: your code will produce illegal HTML, ID's must be unique, yours wont be if $arrays has more than one item

Answer (score 0):

Change the `id` to `class` and then you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use below javascript to fetch all values inside h1 tag.

```
var h1Elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for(var i = 0; i < h1Elements.length; i++)
{
    alert(h1Elements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

**Note**:- `Id` must be unique in DOM. You should use `Class` if it is in loop.

Answer (score 0):

`id`s must be unique. Use a class in the php:

```
<h1 class="my-class"><?php echo  $row['field_name'];?></h1>
```

Then call `document.getElementsByClassName("my-class")` in your javascript, and iterate over the results:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) alert(els[i].innerHTML);
```